# Copying a whole Dataset into a new SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, database

Is there anyway to take a dataset with all the relationships, and data and structure into a clean empty MS SQL database?

I don't want to have to create the tables in the MS SQL database.

Edit :

I am using VS, C#, and a 1GB xml file. - I currently have this chopped for testing purposes.

I can get the xml to the dataset fine - that works a treat, with all the relationships working fine, but I need to move all the data and structure to a new database. Bear in mind, I do not have my dataset linked to the database.

Thanks,

Phill

Comment: why don't you script the database ?

Comment: The Dataset is from a XSD, with imported XML. But using a xsd to database creator doesn't keep the relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to get data from XML to SQL is to write an application that reads in the XML file (see XML serialization here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh(v=vs.110).aspx) and writes it to the database. This gives you maximum control over how your data is translated to SQL.

Without knowing anything about your setup, I'd use xsd.exe to generate C# wrapper classes, deserialize into these from the XML, and then use Entity Framework or another ORM to map the data across to SQL and save.

LINQ to XML could also be quite handy here.